# How to create a Digital Elevation Model using GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, dem, contour

How to create a DEM starting from layers shapefile "contour lines" and "shares"?

Which module of GRASS do I need to use?

Comment: I would possibly know the steps to follow.

Answer (score 8):

In the GRASS GIS Wiki, there is a dedicated page for this: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM The page demonstrates and compares a number of different methods of converting vector contour lines into raster DEM surfaces including screenshots.